# What is this bendable thing found in a closet?

Tags: closet, identify-a-tool

I found this thing in the closet of a room which someone recently moved out of. It is flexible/bendable. I was wondering what it is?
Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 13):

It's a tripod for cameras (see pic):

[image]

Comment: It's a Gorilla tripod yeah. I imagine this must look like an alien insectoid invader to anyone not into photography :)

Comment: Does the one in my post lack something to hold a camera, phone, mic, or any other device?

Comment: You should be able to screw that black disc in the center down, that's where the camera (or other compatible device) will mount (random example of a similar mount [here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0987/3012/products/1444-main_1200x.jpg?v=1525280217)) :)

Answer (score 2):

It can indeed be used as a tripod for a smallish camera. But also it can be wrapped around something (a tree, pipe, chair leg, your arm) or hung under something to have same camera attached.

Would also work like claws round, say,  bicycle handlebars for the same Gopro type camera. Could also be used to support a microphone.

Answer (score 1):

It's also super handy for holding anything you need held in a weird position.  I've used one of those with a taped-on flashlight under sinks and in wire chases, used one to hold back other wires while soldering one, etc.  Handy little tool.